How to assign radio input value to variable?
I'm working on a form with radio input that has values "yes" and "no".
Here's the code:
<input type="radio" id="haveread" name="check" value="yes"><label for='haveread' >Yes</label>
<input type="radio" id="notread" name="check" value="no"><label for="notread" >No</label> 

I'd like to retrieve the radio input value of the radio that has been checked and assign it to  variable called readStatus
Here's my code:
const readStatus = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked');

I tried checking the variable readStatus on my console.log and it returns null.
However, when i input document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked' on the console.log, which is the content of the variable readStatus, i get what I'm looking for which is the checked radio input.
i am expecting the variable readStatus to also return the checked radio input. I'm very confused as to how this works because I'm basically console.logging the same thing.
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?
Edit:
Here's a screenshot of the project, and the console.log
project screenshot and console

You're trying to grab the selected value before one is selected. You need to run the code later. Maybe at the form submission, maybe at the press of a button, maybe on user input. It's not clear.

Hi, I'm sorry I wasn't clear before. I tried selecting the radio button on my project before i console.log both ways. and console.logging document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked') actually worked fine. It only returns null when i console.log the variable.

"and it returns null" - Then the code is running before the element exists on the page, or before any of the radio buttons have been checked.  Put the JavaScript code at the end of the page and execute it in response to an event, such as clicking on the radio buttons or clicking a button for a form.

"I tried checking the variable readStatus on my console.log and it returns null" because when the code ran nothing matched the selector. JS doesn't do time travel - it follows the sequence of events 1. page loads 2. code runs 3. you interacted with the radio buttons 4. you logged the variable readStatus. In this sequence 2. preceeds 3.. If you try to run the selector code after 3. then it would match because at that point it can. Therefore, if you want the code const readStatus = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked'); to not result in null it has to be after 3.

Hi VLAZ and David, I included a screenshot of the project. Would you mind taking a look ? If I haven't selected a radio button, I understand that it will return null. But I've selected the radio button, then i console.logged both the variable and document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked'). It only returned null for the variable.

@AndreyWidjaja: "If I haven't selected a radio button, I understand that it will return null." - And that's exactly what's happening here.  You've discovered that running document.querySelector() before an element exists which matches the selector results in a null value, and doing the same thing after an element exists which matches the selector results in the matching element.  This is correct and expected behavior.  The matching element has to exist when you search for it, not sometime after you search for it.

Because the variable is assigned before anything is selected. I've explained it twice. I don't know what else you expect.

"I took a picture of myself. Then I put on a yellow jacket. But when I look at the picture -I don't have a jacket. If I look down at my body - I do. How come?" is what you're asking.

@VLAZ I think I'm starting to get what you're trying to say. It's just weird because I've worked with other input types and they all worked in real time.. For example, when I declare input[type='text'] , the input box is empty. Then I load the page and tried typing something in the input box. Console.logging that input box's value actually logged whatever I typed in there..

That means that at the time you ran the code to look up the input and assign it to a variable it matched the selector. That doesn't work with input[type="radio"]:checked because there is nothing checked when the code runs.

@AndreyWidjaja: Look at your selector again.  Specifically the :checked part.  Neither of the inputs are checked when the page loads.  Your textbox example is irrelevant.

(I couldn't find an exact duplicate, but many are vaguely close.  This one used to be somewhat canonical on the subject, but has recently changed to address a more specific problem.  If someone finds one let me know and I can delete this answer.)
querySelector can only find an element if it exists when the code executes.  That element may exist at some point in the future, but there's no way for querySelector to know what is going to exist in the future.
Look closely at the selector you're using:
'input[type="radio"]:checked'

It's looking for a radio input that is checked.  Look closely at your HTML:
<input type="radio" id="haveread" name="check" value="yes"><label for='haveread' >Yes</label>
<input type="radio" id="notread" name="check" value="no"><label for="notread" >No</label>

Neither of the inputs are checked.  So no matching element exists.  So querySelector returns null.
Sometime later you select (check) one of the inputs.
Sometime later you manually run your querySelector operation in the browser console.  At this time it finds the matching input.  Because at this time one of the inputs is checked.
Before you've selected an input, none of the inputs are selected.  After you select one, one of them is selected.

Thank you so much for explaining it so clearly! I think I'm starting to get it. I've ended up just using document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked').value directly to retrieve the checked button value. I'll read up on the post you linked. Thanks again!

it comes down to a few couple of things. so first of all, when are you grabbing the value with the querySelector ? at page ready time ? on an event with an event handler ? so the value changes on the radio button when you select one of the options. thus, you need to add an event listener to the radio buttons that fires when you select an option. in said even handler you can set you readStatus var with the value you grab at that point with the query selector.
I would suggest maybe having a look here for some information and examples on event listeners.

Hi, I included a screenshot in my edited post. So I load the page, selected a radio button, and console.logged readStatus and document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked'). readStatus returned null, document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked') returned the radio element.

When radio buttons (or checkboxes) have the same name they are "grouped". So, you can get the value if you refer to the named form field, like here read. In the example the event target of the change event is the "read" form field. So, you can get the value as a property of that, or (in other situations) reference the "absolute name" for the form field.


document.forms.form01.addEventListener('change', e => {
  let read = e.target.value; //relative
  read = document.forms.form01.read.value; //absolute
  console.log('You read it:', read);
});

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let form = e.target;
  let read = form.read.value; //relative
  console.log('You submit that you read it:', read);
});
<form name="form01">
  <label><input type="radio" name="read" value="yes">Yes</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="read" value="no">No</label>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>




Hi thank you for your input! I'll try implementing this into my project, for now I've found a way to work it out but the code's kind of messy.. Thanks again!

The issue here is that document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked') returns the checked radio input element itself, not its value. To retrieve the value of the checked radio input, you need to access its value property.
Here's how you can fix your code:
const readStatusInput = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked');
let readStatus;

if (readStatusInput) {
    readStatus = readStatusInput.value;
} else {
    // Handle the case where no radio input is checked
    readStatus = null; // Or any other default value you want to assign
}

console.log(readStatus);


We first retrieve the checked radio input element using document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked') and store it in the readStatusInput variable.
Then, we check if readStatusInput is not null (i.e., if there is a checked radio input).
If there is a checked radio input, we assign its value property to the readStatus variable.
If there is no checked radio input, we can handle this case accordingly. In this example, we assign null to the readStatus variable, but you can choose any other default value or perform any other actions you need.


Hi Maria, I tried console.logging readStatus.value and document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked').value too.. readStatus.value returns 'VM65300:1 Uncaught
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
at :1:12' while document.querySelector('input[type=button]:checked').value returns the value of the radio button I selected
